# Setting Preferred Applications from the terminal (CentOS 7)

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, terminal, xfce

I'm making a script which uses `xfconf-query` to change various system settings on mass, however I'm unsure how to set my **Preferred Applications** in the same manner.

[image]

I looked into the `mimeapps.list` file which gets generated in `.config/` in the `Home` directory when you set your Preferred Applications via the GUI. File seems to generate a `[Added Associations]` section.

I created a new user account and placed my own `mimeapps.list` file in the `.config` directory in the hopes it might work, but no luck, unfortunately.

Would anyone know how I can set my Preferred Applications using a terminal command or method similar to `xfconf-query`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried anything with it, but the `xdg-mime` tool looks promising. According to its `man` file, it includes a `default` command that can be used to "Ask the desktop environment to make application the default application for opening files of type mimetype."

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the `xdg-mime` tool. I shall have a look and see if it works for my needs.